# Standard way to clean incoming strings?

Tags: ruby, character-encoding

I integrate with a couple external services where I download a file over http. I find I have to convert/clean the names of the file before using them in my system. So I have things like this in different parts of the code:

```
name = name.encode('UTF-8', 'ASCII-8BIT', invalid: :replace, undef: :replace, replace: '')
name = name.encode('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1', invalid: :replace, undef: :replace, replace: '')
```

In each case I had to ask the service what encoding I should expect.

Is this the only way to go about this, or is there some sort of more standard and generic way to clean an incoming string?

Comment: There's `charlock_holmes`, but that one takes a guess.

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby 1.9.x there is an external and an internal encoding which both default to the global encoding. External files are considered to be in the configured external encoding and are automatically converted into the internal encoding. You can set these encodings globally through `Encoding.default_external` and `Encoding.default_internal`. You can specify them on a per-file basis as arguments to the `open` method as in the following example:

```
File.open('/path/to/some/file', 'r', external_encoding: 'US-ASCII', internal_encoding: 'UTF-8')
```

Notice that you can also specify each one alone.

See [this blog post](http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/ruby_19s_three_default_encodings) for additional information.